# How to support "per request" scope

Tags: inversifyjs

I want to get the user token from the middlewares and injected into controller, is it possible?

```
class TaskController {
    @inject private currentUser

    @Post('/tasks')
    addTask() {
        if (!hasPermission(currentUser)) throw new Error("Unauthorized.")
        // ...
    }
}
```

I hope the injected currentUser above can be retrieved from some middlewares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, InversifyJS onlysupports singleton and trainsient scopes. We have a [roadmap item](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/218) to investigate new types of scope.

We are also working on the support for middleware at the moment but it is not fully ready. You can contact the development team on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/inversify/InversifyJS) to find out more about our plans, help us or requests features.

Answer (score 1):

InversifyJS has had the `inRequestScope()` for some time now, but it doesn't help much with the container-per-http-request case, because InversifyJS's request scope is actually tied to a single call to `get`, that is, each call to `get` is considered a Request, and it will only work as intended for an HTTP context if only have a single call to `get` per request.

I had the same problem as yours: from within a middleware, I needed to pull the current user from the request and inject that information into a `CurrentUser` class, so that information could later be accessed by other services down the line.

For this, I needed at least two calls to `get<CurrentUser>`: one in the middleware and another for instantiating the controller/handler for the request.

So, `inRequestScope` is not a viable solution, and `inSingletonScope` or `inTransientScope` are also out of the question.

I ended up creating the `ScopedContainer` class you can see down below.

First, **this is how you would use it**:

```js
// register-global-dependencies.ts
ScopedContainer.globalContainer = (() => {
  const container = new Container();
  container
    .bind<SomeSingletonDep>(TOKENS.SomeSingletonDep)
    .to(SomeSingletonDep)
    .inSingletonScope();
  return container;
})();
```

☝️ This allows you to still have Singleton dependencies.

```js
// register-scoped-dependencies.ts
import "register-global-dependencies";

ScopedContainer.postConfigure((container) => {
  container
    .bind<RequestSpecificDep>(TOKENS.RequestSpecificDep)
    .to(RequestSpecificDep)
    .inSingletonScope();
});
```

☝️ This controls which dependencies should be resolved once per HTTP request.

```js
// lambda-handler.ts
import "register-scoped-dependencies";

handler = (event, context) => {
  const requestId = event.requestContext.requestId;
  const container = ScopedContainer.for(requestId);

  try {
    // This will be the same for every request
    const singletonDep = container.get(TOKENS.SomeSingletonDep);

    // And this will be a new instance for every request
    const requestSpecificDep = container.get(TOKENS.RequestSpecificDep);
  }
  finally {
    ScopedContainer.remove(requestId);
  }
}
```

---

This is the `ScopedContainer` class:

```js
import { Container, interfaces } from "inversify";

const DEFAULT_SCOPE_ID = "__default__";

export type PostConfigureAction = (container: Container) => void;

export type ScopedContainerCache = {
  [id: string]: Container;
};

export class ScopedContainer {
  private static _postConfigureActions: PostConfigureAction[] = [];
  private static readonly _instances: ScopedContainerCache = {};

  /**
   * Options object to use when creating a new container for a
   * scope ID.
   */
  static containerOptions: interfaces.ContainerOptions;

  /**
   * A global container instance, which enables truly
   * singleton instances when using a scoped container. All scoped
   * containers reference the global container as parent.
   *
   * @example
   * ScopedContainer.globalContainer = (() => {
   *   const container = new Container();
   *   container
   *     .bind<ClassInSingletonScope>(TOKENS.ClassInSingletonScope)
   *     .to(ClassInSingletonScope)
   *     .inSingletonScope();
   *   return container;
   * })();
   */
  static globalContainer: Container;

  /**
   * Optional function to configure the global container.
   * An alternative to directly setting the @see globalContainer property.
   */
  static configureGlobalContainer: (container: Container) => void;

  /**
   * Returns a @see Container that is unique to the specified scope.
   * If this is the first time getting the container for the scope, then a
   * new container will be created using the provided factory. Any post configure
   * actions will also be applied to the new container instance.
   * @param scopeId Any string to identify the scope (e.g. current request ID).
   * @returns A @see Container that is unique to the specified scope.
   */
  static for(scopeId = DEFAULT_SCOPE_ID): Container {
    let container = this._instances[scopeId];
    if (!container) {
      container = this.makeNewContainer();
      this._instances[scopeId] = container;
    }
    return container;
  }

  /**
   * Unbinds the @see Container (i.e. container.unbindAll()) and removes
   * it from the cache.
   * @param scopeId
   */
  static remove(scopeId = DEFAULT_SCOPE_ID): void {
    let container = this._instances[scopeId];
    if (!container) return;
    container.unbindAll();
    delete this._instances[scopeId];
  }

  /**
   * Runs the @method remove method on all instances.
   */
  static removeAll(): void {
    Object.keys(this._instances).forEach((key) => this.remove(key));
  }

  /**
   * Adds a post configure action.
   * @remarks A registration with .inSingletonScope() will work as .inRequestScope() should,
   * that is, a new instance will be created for each instance of ScopedContainer.
   * @param fn A function that will be run everytime a new @see Container is created.
   * @returns The @see ScopedContainer itself, to allow chaining.
   */
  static postConfigure(fn: PostConfigureAction): ScopedContainer {
    this._postConfigureActions.push(fn);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Removes any post configure actions.
   */
  static resetPostConfigureActions(): void {
    this._postConfigureActions = [];
  }

  private static makeNewContainer(): Container {
    const container = this.ensureGlobalContainer().createChild(this.containerOptions);
    this._postConfigureActions.forEach((action) => action(container));
    return container;
  }

  private static ensureGlobalContainer(): Container {
    if (!this.globalContainer) {
      const container = new Container(this.containerOptions);
      this.configureGlobalContainer?.(container);
      this.globalContainer = container;
    }
    return this.globalContainer;
  }
}
```

---

https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/1076#issuecomment-1045179988